# Calendar component in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, momentjs, nuxt.js

My first time posting a question here.

im trying to create a Calendar in nuxt to use with registered hours.
The code i paste here works to create the calendar, but i would like to make the days array
an array of objects instead so it not only holds the date but also a property of workhours, and overtime etc.

But when i try to make it an object in the Data() i cannot figure out how to get the date from the load days code.
Hope someone can help

```
<template>
  <div id="container" >
    <div>{{ $moment().format('dddd - do.MMMM.yyyy') }}</div>

   <!--eslint-disable -->
    <div class="grid-container">
    <p class="grid-item">September</p>
    <p class="grid-item"></p>
    <p class="grid-item">A</p>
    <p class="grid-item">O</p>
    <p class="grid-item">Fl</p>
    <p class="grid-item">S</p>
    <p class="grid-item">Fe</p>
    </div>
  <div v-for="(day, index) in days" class="grid-container">
    <p class="grid-item">{{ day.format("Do") }}</p>
    <p class="grid-item">{{ day.format("dddd") }}</p>
    <p class="grid-item">0</p>
    <p class="grid-item">0</p>
    <p class="grid-item">0</p>
    <p class="grid-item">0</p>
    <p class="grid-item">0</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>/* eslint-disable */
import moment from 'moment'


export default {
  data(){
    return{
    days: []
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    //load days
    let monthDate = moment().startOf('month')
    this.days = [...Array(monthDate.daysInMonth())].map((_, i) => {
      return monthDate.clone().add(i, 'day')
    })
  }

}
</script>
<style scoped>
  .grid-container{
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;

  }
  .grid-item {
    width: 125px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 5px;
    font-size:16px;
    text-align: center;
  }

</style>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console ?

Comment: There are not any errors when i runt this code, this works. But i want the array of days to be an array of objects with properties instead, something like
data(){
    return{
    days: [
{
day: monthDate.day
}
]
    }
  },

im just not sure how to do that, cause console says monthDate is undefined when i run this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are constructing your array you can create an array of objects like this :

```js
let monthDate = moment().startOf("month");
this.days = [...Array(monthDate.daysInMonth())].map((_, i) => {
  return {
    date: monthDate.clone().add(i, "day"),
    workhours: 0,
    overtime: 0
  };
});
```

In the map function we return an object instead of just a single property

```html
<div v-for="(day, index) in days" :key="index" class="grid-container">
  <p class="grid-item">{{ day.date.format("Do") }}</p>
  <p class="grid-item">{{ day.date.format("dddd") }}</p>
  <p class="grid-item">{{ day.workhours }}</p>
  <p class="grid-item">{{ day.overtime }}</p>
</div>
```